# facebook getResponse() method - allow login

Tags: c#, facebook

I am currently working on facebook. I would like to ask how to `GetResponse()` from the http page. I have the url to the Facebook login that will login using my c# application but when i click allow the exploer page links to error. Why? WHat am i doing wrong? Should I redirect to another page after the client clicks allow? How to programatically do that? THX. In my url i have a redirect option.

Comment: yep that's not easy to understand or help you like that ..

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
     FB.init({ 
        appId:'YOUR_APP_ID', cookie:true, 
        status:true, xfbml:true 
     });
     FB.api('/me', function(user) {
       if(user != null) {
          var image = document.getElementById('image');
          image.src = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + user.id + '/picture';
          var name = document.getElementById('name');
          name.innerHTML = user.name
       }
     });
   </script>
```